# MSSQL Insert 10 random rows for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a MSSQL table that holds the IDs, say **TBL1**.

I also have another table which holds about 1M data; named **TBL2**

What I am trying to do is, I'd like to insert 10 random rows from **TBL2** into a new table **TBL3** for each ID in **TBL1**.

Currently I am using CURSOR to loop through TBL1 but it takes forever especially when the table size is very large.

Any alternative suggestions regarding how to do that?

Thanks.

EDIT: 
TBL1 and TBL2 does not have any linkage, no ID etc.
TBL2 does only have pure data.

Comment: Yes, I can get random results no problem; but the insertion is the main problem.

Comment: If there is no linkage then your question is not valid.

Comment: My question is completely valid, in no place i mentioned any linkage. 

Example: You have 100k people in table 1, you have 1M hobbies in table 2, you want to assign 10 random hobbies to each person.

Comment: You can insert 10 id from table1 into table3 then update the table3 with random hobbies.

Comment: Always post the code showing what you've tried. Even if you're looking for a different way to do it, it gives readers a frame of reference to help understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the query below to get a random join between two unrelated tables. As I used inner join, it will limit the number of rows to be the minimum of the two tables' row count (which seems to be what you want). You can then run it 10 times (I used `GO 10` for that).

```
insert into TBL3
select t1.col1, t2.col2
from
    (select row_number() over (order by NEWID()) rownum, col1 from TBL1) t1
inner join
    (select row_number() over (order by NEWID()) rownum, col2 from TBL2) t2
on t1.rownum = t2.rownum

go 10
```